# anyone tell me the difference for RRECOMMENDS and RDEPENDS

Tags: bitbake

I seldom use `RRECOMMENDS` and I don't know what its real use is. It seems to
install just one package..

```
-RDEPENDS_${PN} = "kernel-module-tun"
+RRECOMMENDS_${PN} = "kernel-module-tun"
```

Can anyone explain the difference between the above two lines of code?

Does `RRECOMMENDS` install `kernel-module-tun`? If not then what is it used for?

Answer (score 13):

I'll try.  Both of these variable define recipe dependencies.

```
-RDEPENDS_${PN} = "kernel-module-tun"
```

RDEPENDS is a hard, runtime dependency.  So anything listed extends the functionality to which it applies but MUST be installed for the package to run correctly.  If a listed package is not present, or not yet built, the dependent package is still able to build successfully. The YoctoProject Reference Manual includes a nice description of this variable.  Please see [Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html)

```
+RRECOMMENDS_${PN} = "kernel-module-tun"
```

RRECOMMENDS is a soft, runtime dependency.  So anything listed extends the functionality to which it applies, but is not a requirement for building.  There are a few more quirks about RRECOMMENDS that you may wish to look up in the YoctoProject Reference Manual, which seems to be the best resource for this type of material at this time:  [Reference Manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html)

So to answer your question, `RRECOMMENDS` will install `kernel-module-tun` if it is available.  If it is not, the build will continue.  The opposite would be using the `RDEPENDS` statement, which, if `kernel-module-tun` could not be found, would cause an error during the build process.